# SVG—bbox to large for group from nested svg

Tags: svg, bounding-box

I am building an svg-based application which uses one, »root« svg as Viewport/Canvas. Within this one I load one SVG which sets up all the graphics, that one is quiet large (~18.000px * 800px, 4MB). I am trying to create a parallax effect, which is working for primitive graphic element like `<rect>`. But it does not work for `<g>` elements.

It is difficult to post relevant code, since the graphic has grown very big, so below you can see an example for the basic setup:

```
<svg class="root" width="1000" height="800">
    <g class="container" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,<dx>,<dy>)">
        <svg width="16000" height="800">

        <!-- a lot of graphics here -->

        <g>
            <!-- the group with all the graphics for the parallax  -->
            <g class="parallax" transform="matrix(<crazy inkscape values here>);">
            </g>
        </g>

        <!-- a lot of graphics here -->

        </svg>
    </g>
</svg>
```

All in all I need to access the width of the whole group to calculate the parallax offset, therefore I am using:

```
<g>.getBBox();
```

what returns a value whose width is about `2.5` times too big. I replaced the group with a `<Rect>` in the same dimensions at the same place in the DOM and everything works alright.

What could cause the returned bounding bounding box grow, probably `<gradient>-`, `<symbol>-`, or `<use>-` elements ?

I appreciate any Idea.

btw: The conversion of coordinates is already taken into account here, at least as far a possible. I tested this in FF and Chromium — the same thing everywhere…

Thanks in ahead!

**Edit**

I guess I found the reason for the error. This time it wasn't mine. The Graphics were delivered by an Illustrator, using Illustrator and in the original file I found several empty path. They spanned the bbox to 0/0, even if no real point was there...

Comment: Empty paths contributing (or not) to the bbox have been discussed here: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-svg/2014Feb/0065.html.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the following is the full solution, but let's start here for discussion purposes.

The following is an inline svg with a width=400 height=400, but contains a `<g>` element with some elements that exceed those sizes. I want to fit the elements in the `<g>` to my 400x400 inline svg.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        </head>
        <body style='font-family:arial'>
            <center>
            <div id="svgDiv" style='background-color:lightgreen;width:400px;height:400px;'>
<svg id="mySVG" width="400" height="400"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
    <g id="myG">
    <circle cx=1000 cy=500 r=300 fill="red" />
    <rect x=300 y=200 width=500 height=300 fill="blue" />
    </g>
</svg>
</div>
<button onClick=fitG() >fit G</button>

            <br />SVG Source:<br />
            <textarea id=svgSourceValue style='font-size:110%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:200px'></textarea>
            <br />Javascript:<br />
            <textarea id=jsValue style='border-radius:26px;font-size:110%;font-weight:bold;color:midnightblue;padding:16px;background-color:beige;border-width:0px;font-size:100%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:400px'></textarea>
            </center>
            <div id='browserDiv' style='padding:5px;position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;background-color:gainsboro;'>OK in:IE11/CH32/FF28<br /></div>
<script id=myScript>
//---button--
function fitG()
{
    var bb=myG.getBBox()
    var bbx=bb.x
    var bby=bb.y
    var bbw=bb.width
    var bbh=bb.height
    //---center of import---
    var cx=bbx+.5*bbw
    var cy=bby+.5*bbh
    //---create scale: ratio of desired width vs current width--
    var width=390
    var scale=width/bbw
    //---where to move it---
    var targetX=200
    var targetY=200
    //---move its center to target x,y ---
    var transX=(-cx)*scale + targetX
    var transY=(-cy)*scale + targetY
    myG.setAttribute("transform","translate("+transX+" "+transY+")scale("+scale+" "+scale+")")

    svgSourceValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML
}
</script>
            <script>
            document.addEventListener("onload",init(),false)
            function init()
            {
                svgSourceValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML
                jsValue.value=myScript.text
            }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Ah, I see your Edit above. OK glad you found the problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Fiddling with bounding boxes is always a fun on its own…